# Taylor series of the function $f(x)=\ln\left[(3x+4)^{x+2}\right]$ and its convergence interval

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification, taylor-expansion

> I would like to compute the Taylor series of the function $f(x)=\ln\left[(3x+4)^{x+2}\right]$ around $c=-1$.

My work so far:

Let $y=x+1$. Then $x=y-1,$ so

$\begin{aligned}f(x)&=(x+2)\ln(3x+4)\\&=(x+2)\ln(3(y-1)+4)\\&=(x+2)\ln(3y+1)=(x+2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(3y)^n}n,\forall y\in(-1/3,1/3)\\&=(x+2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{3^n(x+1)^n}n,\color{blue}{\forall x\in(-1-1/3,-1+1/3)}\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{3^n(x+1)^{n+1}}n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{3^n(x+1)^n}n\\&=3(x+1)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left((-1)^{n-2}\frac{3^{n-1}}{n-1}+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{3^n}n\right)(x+1)^n\\&=3(x+1)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-2}3^{n-1}n+(-1)^{n-1}3^n(n-1)}{(n-1)n}(x+1)^n\\&=3(x+1)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-2}3^{n-1}(n-3(n-1))}{(n-1)n}(x+1)^n\\&=3(x+1)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}3^{n-1}(2n-3)}{(n-1)n}(x+1)^n\end{aligned}$

I think the interval of convergence of the series is $(-4/3,-2/3)$. I think the first part shouldn't be invalid as I also checked the formula $(\ln(ax+b))^{(n)}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!a^n}{(ax+b)^n}\Bigg/\frac1{n!}$ for the coefficients in the expansion of $\ln(ax+b)$, but I have doubts about the rest.

Have I made any error and is there any more simple form?

---

**Edit:**

I forgot to check the convergence in the endpoints $-1\pm1/3$. If we plug $x=-1+1/3$ and $-1-1/3$ into $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{3^n(x+1)^n}n,$$ we obtain the alternating series
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac1n$ and the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{2n-1}}n=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n,$ respectively.

Since $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a strictly decreasing sequence of positive numbers converging to $0$, the first series converges by the Leibniz criterium, so my initial answer was wrong, while the second diverges, as mentioned in the comments, and the interval of convergence is $(-1-1/3,-1+1/3]$.

Comment: The ratio test will confirm that the radius of convergence is $1/3$, so the interval of convergence contains $(-4/3, -2/3)$. Have you checked for convergence at the endpoints?

Comment: @shoteyes, I haven't, but I've included them now. I think the series converges in the endpoints by the Leibniz criterium.

Comment: The terms for the series when $x = -1 - 1/3$ are incorrect. It should be similar to the harmonic series and thus divergent.

Comment: @shoteyes, thank you. Now I see the exponent was wrong. Thank you for the correction.